# how to set zone in dojo?

Tags: dojo, zone

if the time in mysql is set to '2011-08-07 08:00:00', the value of dijit.form.TimeTextBox will be showed like this '2011-08-07 16:00:00'. The diffence of time between mysql and web is 8 hours,so i think the default value of zone in dojo is set to 'UTC'(not 'BEIJING'). Who can tell me how to deal with it?

I am wishing your help,thanks!

Answer (score -1):

this should help you http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/date/locale/format.html#dojo-date-locale-format

After you get the data from server, format it with your desired locale and add it as a value on the textbox